# Can i call a method of the class in constructor and which arguments will it get?

Tags: java

Can i call a method of the class in constructor and which arguments will it get?
for instance I have

I need to set a string into object, when i create it.

but not via constructor arguments.

```
interface a 
{
      void set(String s);
}

public class b implements a
{
String s;

public void set(String s)
{
   do smthn
}


public b(s)
{
       set(???);
}
```

Comment: please rephrase your question, it is totally un-understandable

Comment: @elefasGR yes, it's derstandable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i call a method of the class in constructor

Yes, however it's usually considered a bad idea to call instance method on an object while it is being constructed.

> and which arguments will it get?

The ones you pass it.  The only implied argument is the instance object `this`

Answer (score 0):

It will receive the arguments that you send, for instance

```
public b(String s){
       set(s);
}


public b(String s){
       set(s.concat("hello"));
}

public b(String s){
       set(s.replace(".", ","));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your constructor in class b, you have to declare the object type of your parameter. Then you can pass it to your set method if it is a String

```
public b(String s) 
{ 
    set(s);
}
```